# An alternative definition of the limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, alternative-proof

In a course on real analysis one usually comes across the definition of the limit of a function:

Given a function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then if $c\in A$ is an limit point of $A$, we say that

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = L
\end{align}

If

\begin{align}
\forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0} 
0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon 
\end{align}

When one uses this definition of a limit in a proof, it tends to get a bit messy, sometimes you have to do this "trick" where you restrict $\delta$ to always be less than a certain constant, to get some constant lower bounds in either of the inequalities. It also happens frequently that one starts with a $\delta$ and investigates what happens to $|f(x)-L|$, and then from that guess what a suitable relationship between $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ should be. This approach seems to be a bit convoluted at times, so I propose an alternative definition which I believe is more rational

Given $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ with $c\in A$ as before, then if there is a surjective function

\begin{align}
g:(0,a)\to(0,b)
\end{align}

That satisfies

\begin{align} 
0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<g(\delta)
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to c}=L
\end{align}

This seems superficially more complicated, because now suddenly we have to check the surjectivity of a function, but what is interesting is that both quantifiers and a whole variable ($\varepsilon$) is now imbedded into a single statement about a function. The motivation behind the definition is that if one can find such a $g$, then given any $\varepsilon>0$, one can find $0<\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon'\in(0,b)$, and since it is in the image of $g$ there is some $\delta$ such that $g(\delta)=\varepsilon'$ and from there you can prove that the limit holds in the traditional sense. Note that one can also prove surjectivity by proving that a function is bijective, and you can prove the latter by constructing the inverse, thereby entirely avoiding the use of quantifiers.

My questions then are:
Does this alternative definition seem correct, and useful?
Is there something analogous to this that is already used?

Comment: The proposition in your second displayed formula should have $0<|x-a|<\delta$, not $|x-a|<\delta$, otherwise you are defining continuity.

Comment: @Carlyle The point is that you need to *prevent* $x=a$: if $f(x)=0$ everywhere except for $f(0)=1$, we still have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0$. Incidentally, your proposed definition (once fixed) is basically an instance of the logical technique of [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form), whose role is exactly to replace complicated-quantifier expressions with an $\exists_{functions}\forall_{elements}$-expression.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I appreciate the comment. I am still not quite sure what the problem is, are you saying that when I add the quantifier over $x$, the problem is fixed, or still not?

Comment: @Carlyle I was talking about the first and yes, both are wrong. The statements with $|x-a|<\delta$ define what everyone else calls "$f$ is continuous at $x=a$ (with $f(a)=L$)"

Comment: @Carlyle Adding the requirement $x\not=c$ would do the job, as would adding "$0<$" appropriately. But what's written right now is not quite correct.

Comment: Your proposition replaces $\forall \varepsilon, \exists \delta$ by $\exists a, \exists b, \exists g, \forall \delta$. On first impression, this does not look like an improvement.

Comment: @NoahSchweber but does adding a quantifier over $x$ not ensure that the condition "gets checked" for all those $x\neq c$ as well?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, generally complexity is better understood with the amount of switches between quantifiers, a string like $\exists_a\exists_b\exists_c\exists_d\exists_f$ is a lot simpler than $\forall_a\exists_b\forall_c\exists_d$. Even though the latter has less quantifiers, so I don't think this is that big of a concern, especially considering one usually thinks of the domain and co-domain as being information about the function, and you could naturally place the condition on $a$ and $b$ together with the condition that $g$ is surjective

Comment: @Carlyle Agreed. Still, there are more variables in your definition, so a principle such as Ockham razor would prefer the usual definition. And I fail seeing a case where the new definition would be useful.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, $a$ and $b$ are technically variables, but they are still in some non-formal way "less variable" than $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in the normal definition, in the sense that they are only a variable until you decide upon some fixed numerical value for them, so I still don't think that this alone is enough to disregard the definition, but usefulness might well be, for that, I know of at least one limit which is at most the same difficulty to prove using this definition, which is the limit of $\frac{1}{x}$ as $x\to a\neq 0$. But it remains to be seen if there are more examples

Answer (score 5):

You asked: "Is there something analogous to this that is already used?"

There is indeed a way of defining limits with fewer quantifier alternations, as you suggested.  This way can be viewed as a formalisation of the approach with functions that you sketched.  Namely, one has $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) =L$ if and only if for all $x$ infinitely close to $c$ but different from $c$, one has $f(x)\approx L$ where $\approx$ is the relation of infinite proximity.  Here $a\approx b$ iff $a-b$ is infinitesimal, and a number is infinitesimal if it is smaller in absolute value than every positive standard real number.  A recent breakthrough showed that such a framework can be achieved conservatively over ZF (without the axiom of choice and without ultrafilters).  See [here](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/spot.html) for further details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm sorry that someone downvoted your it, it seems perfectly fine to me

Comment: @Carlyle, perhaps they feel that the real numbers could not *possibly* contain infinitesimals.  Why, Cantor already said so.