# Laying out an epsilon delta proof clearly

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I’m working on how to set out epsilon delta proofs. There are a few questions on here about how to do these proofs but the advice about how to set them out is mingled in the answers with advice about the proof itself and I want to ensure specifically that the layout of the proof is as clear as possible. I’ve seen other people write epsilon delta proofs on whiteboards etc as just a long line of inequalities with $=\epsilon\quad\square$ at the end, but the long chain of expressions on both sides with a mix of inequalities with the equal sign at the end feels very messy to me, so I’m trying to work on a format that I feels flows better and is more understandable. It’s some time before we get to epsilon delta proofs in my course, but before I actually submit work using this proof layout, could you give me advice on how to improve it please? In particular I feel uncomfortable about the “Examine” section below.

Say I’m asked to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 2}(x^2-4x+5)=1$$ and I’ve done my scratch work to find $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$, what do you think about laying out the proof like this?

**Proof:**
Recall that $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L\Longleftrightarrow\forall \epsilon>0~\exists~\delta>0~\text{such that}~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\text{, we have}~ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon\\
$$
Therefore we must prove that for any arbitrary $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that for all real $x$ with $0<|x-2| <\delta$, we have $$|(x^2-4x+5)-1|<\epsilon.$$

Given $\epsilon$, choose $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$, and suppose we have $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<|x-2|<\delta$.

$$
\begin{align*}\text{Examine}~&|(x^2-4x+5)-1| \\
\Rightarrow& |x^2-4x+4| \\
\Rightarrow& |(x-2)^2| \\
\Rightarrow& (x-2)^2 \\
\\
\text{So}~|(x^2-4x+5)-1| \Rightarrow& (x-2)^2.
\\[12pt]
\text{But we know}~|x-2|&<\delta\\
\text{so}~(x-2)^2&<\delta^2\\
\text{and since}~\delta &= \sqrt{\epsilon} \\
\text{we have}~(x-2)^2&<\epsilon \\
\\[12pt]
\text{Therefore}~|(x^2-4x+5)-1|&<\epsilon. \quad \square
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: For precisely the reason you mention here, the proofs generally being messy because they involve this "experimental phase" and then a "verifying phase", I attempted to find an equivalent definition that could be used to write better flowing proofs, here is that definition: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754562/an-alternative-definition-of-the-limit-of-a-function

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure I know enough to be able to do it that way but I will bear it in mind as I learn more.  Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, the best style of a proof depends on the reason why a proof is needed. When you're learning math, a very detailed style of proof with many steps (like this one) is beneficial because it enables you to get feedback on whether you understand the requirements of the proof correctly. If you're a working mathematician trying to communicate with other working mathematicians, a more efficient style of proof is preferred. Given that you are at a stage where you want to know how to organize a proof of a fairly simple limit, I think what you've written is just about perfect.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with this proof.  Every step follows from what comes before.

Getting down to small details.

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L\Longleftrightarrow\forall \epsilon>0~\exists~\delta>0\cdots$

This is a definition and not a logical implication, so I wouldn't use "if and only if" here.  You could say "from the definition," or just state the definition.

I like the line that says what you are going to attempt to show.  It might not be necessary, but it makes is clear what will follow.

I would do the algebra that follows before making the statement setting $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}.$ In most of these proofs, it will not be clear why you have chosen that value of $\delta$ but if you show the algebra first it is more clear.

Drop the implication arrow between your lines of algebra.  You should not spam equals signs down lines of algebra, either.  In the line "$|(x^2-4x+5)-1| \Rightarrow (x-2)^2$" that is an equality, not an implication.  But, I would cut that line altogether.

The next bit uses a few too many words and too many lines to say what you need to say.

The last line, $\text{Therefore}~|(x^2-4x+5)-1|<\epsilon$  isn't what you set out to show.  If you want to tie off your proof with a bow, say something more like "we have shown the existence of a $\delta$ that satisfies the limit definition for any $\epsilon,$ as required."

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. I’m taking it on board and liking the proof format a lot more as a result.